# Which hyperplane separates these two classes?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

I have a dataset of 3 dimensional points in two classes, I want to separate between the two. As the plot suggests, these two are completely separable but I don't know the formula to form the separating hyperplane. Any suggestion? Here is the dataset: http://ge.tt/5Vr9HG82/v/0?c

[image]

Comment: Separable does not mean linearly separable. A hyperplane in 3d space is just a plane. That data does not look anything close to linearly separable

Comment: I never said I want to linearly separate these two in this space. By the way, they will be linearly separable in a higher dimensional space.

Comment: But you asked about a hyperplane, and that does mean linear separability. And you said three dimensions, in which space (at least graphically) the data does not look linearly separable

Comment: ok. I should have been more precise. I want a separating hyperplane in another space in which this data is linearly separable:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an SVM with a Gaussian kernel. A Gaussian kernel will yield a smooth boundary. From the plot, it seems this is the case (?). With properly tuned parameters (parameter C in SVM, and Gaussian width), the SVM should be able to classify the two classes. Parameter tuning can be done by cross validation. Many SVM packages will do  it for you automatically given a list of parameter candidates. In general, you do not need to come up with a formula for the decision boundary. That is the job of a learning algorithm. You may want to rescale your variables before training an SVM.

Comment: Best accuracy I reached is about 60% using 10-fold cross validation with tuned sigma for RBF kernel. I tried a grid of C=10^-1:10 and sigma=c(0.001,0.01,1,2,4,6,10) to tune the svm.

Comment: You said the two classes are completely separable. If they are, even poor parameters should give a good separating hyperplane. This is strange. No idea.

Comment: If the data are linearly separable you should get 100% accuracy with a plain linear SVM

Comment: @ssdecontrol I guess he means separable with a possibly curvy decision boundary.

Comment: But that's not a hyperplane. Something is being confused or omitted here

Comment: A hyperplane in a feature space is the same as a curvy decision boundary in the original space.